# Lamination on a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

How can lamination help reduce eddy currents? I understood that it reduces them, by making their circulation incomplete, or something like that. Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: And if lamination works, do wires work better?

Answer (score 2):

In lamination, sheets of metal are separated by insulators. Charge can't flow between plates (they're insulated from each other), so there can't be large eddy currents perpendicular to the plate.

Obviously large eddy currents can still flow on the plane of the metal sheets. If you properly align the source of the emf and the plate, you can rid of most of the eddy currents.

Even with this, there are still tiny eddy currents in the single plates themselves. But these do not dissipate nearly as much energy.

Comment: Could it affect the rate of current in the conductor? Let say we have a laminated conductor and a non-laminated conductor, they both should carry the same amount of current?

Comment: If the current doesn't have a component perpendicular to the lamination, no. That said, because it is part metal and part non-conductor, the total throughput is reduced, just like using a thinner cable would.